# determine if a file contains a string in android

Tags: android, string, file

As the title says, I'm looking for a short function that reads in a file if there is a particular string and, //do something if present. For example if in the test.txt file is present the string TestString.
Someone would be so kind to suggest me a method?

Answer (score 1):

```
  InputStream is = //--open an input stream from file--
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
  String line;

  while ( (line = rd.readLine()) != null ){
      if(line.matches(".*TestString.*")){ //--regex of what to search--
          //--do something---
          break; //--if not want to search further--
      }
  }
```