# Determine if word is in word list from file

Tags: java, android

I have a file I'm reading through android.  It is essentially just a list of words.  I have an edit text where the user enters a word, and then I need to check if that word is in the list of words.  I can get the file, I then add all the words to a String, and I can check if the characters of the word entered are located in the list of words,  but I can't check if it's the word alone or not.  For example, if the user enters 'bro' and bro is not in the word list, but 'brother' is, it returns true.  The words are each on their own line, so I tried testing 'bro' as '\nbro\n', but that doesn't work.  Any ideas?  If you need code posted let me know, but I don't think it helps much

Comment: You can put the words in an `ArrayList` and search the list.

Comment: Why don't you use a resource file and read it in as an array?  How big is this "word list"?

Comment: How would I put it in an array list?  It's a large word list, and I thought adding it to an array list might take a while, though it will probably be done in background anyway

Comment: @tjorlando we need information as to how large this list is, either in KiB or number of words to give you guidance here.

Comment: Word list can be 20kb give or take

Comment: 20kb isn't that big; I'd read it into memory. Making the user wait for file I/O to validate a word would take too long. With the word list in memory, the user could get instant feedback.

Comment: Read words into a **Map<String, Boolean>**. The lookup is then O(1) (amortized) with `map.contains(key)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was looking for.  It was an unanswered question linked to at the bottom of the page.  I needed to use a buffered reader to read the file, which allows for reading one line at a time.  Thank you for your help.  [Using Buffered Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14544672/935870)